# How to mount a cifs Partition for docker-compose?

Tags: linux, mount, docker, samba, docker-compose

I want docker-compose to mount one of the volumes to a mounted CIFS partition.

I used the seafile docker-compose file and changed the volumes to

```
...    
  db:
...
    volumes:
     - /mnt/nas_share/seafile/database:/var/lib/mysql 
...
 seafile: 
...
    volumes:
      - /mnt/nas_share/seafile/data:/shared
```

my `fstab` looks as follows

```
fstab
---
...
# /dev/nvme0n1p3
UUID=XXXXXX /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1
...
//192.168.1.110/seafile /mnt/nas_share/seafile cifs _netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials/share,uid=1000,gid=984  0 1
```

when I use the `volumes` in the same directory as compose file, which is in `/home/user/seafile/` as

```
...    
  DB:
...
    volumes:
     - ./database:/var/lib/mysql 
...
 seafile: 
...
    volumes:
      - ./seafile/data:/shared
```

All is fine. that leads me to believe it is a problem with the mounting.

I guess I am missing some form of permission or access rights. Therefore I would need clarification on pointing a volume to a `CIFS` mounted drive for docker-compose.